# Tracking small white circles of the same size in pure black background

Tags: computer-vision

I have four identical white circles in a picture of which the size is small , the background is pure black. The circles are constantly moving. How to keep a record of the trajectory of all circles? Does traditional tracking methods have a hard time because feature extraction is hard?

Answer (score 0):

Standard tracking and/or optical flow are probably an overkill.

You can start by doing connected component analysis on the image, to isolate the circles.  Then search for each one what is the closest circle in the previous frame.  If they do are not allowed to overlap, this should suffice.

If they do overlap, you will probably need to record this and when they leave each other, use their last known direction to determine which is which.

If they overlap with the same trajectory, then you're probably left without options, unless there is another way to tell them apart.